# Thesis' title-page template, Simple style with only a vertical line

Tags: titles, thesis

Goodmorning everybody,
I am compliting the last page of my bachelor degree thesis. As last page, I have decided to leave the title-page ;)

I have searched for some nice templates around the web, and I have come to the idea of a very simple and neated page with only a vertical line and the requested data (thesis title, personal name, univ. name, supervisor name).

The template I am trying to recreate is the following (from Siarhei Khirevich's discussion paper): [Template](http://www.khirevich.com/downloads/Dissertation_Khirevich%28print%29.pdf) (26 MB) But, basically, I do not know how to do it.

What I have achieved is some like this (I have found this code on another webpage, but unfortunately I can't find it out anymore ;( )

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\hbox{
\hspace*{0\textwidth} % Whitespace to the left of the title page
\rule{1.5pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box which restricts text to less than the width of the page
        {\noindent\Huge\bfseries Complexity \\[0.3\baselineskip] Economics}\\[2\baselineskip] % Title
        {\large \textit{with the supervision of Prof.}}\\[4\baselineskip] %     Tagline or further description
        {\Large \textsc{My name}} % 

        \vspace{0.1\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
        {\noindent University of X \\
        Course
        Accademic Year
        }\\[\baselineskip] % Publisher and logo
    }
}
\end{document}
```

The goal:
[image]

Could someone please address me on how to get the template done? ;)
Thanks
;)

Comment: Thanks to @Johannes_B for having edited my previous post! Sorry for having insterted directly the image myself!

Answer (score 4):

This is the rough approximation without `tikz`. With `tikz`, it is cake walk.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=2in,top=0cm,bottom=0cm}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\rule{1.5pt}{0.3\textheight}% Vertical line

\vspace{5mm}
\noindent
{\Huge\bfseries Complexity \\[0.3\baselineskip]
Economics}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\large \textit{with the supervision of Prof.}}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large \textsc{My name}} %

\vspace{0.1\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
\noindent
University of X \\
Course
Accademic Year
\\[\baselineskip] % Publisher and logo
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.5pt}{0.35\textheight}}% Vertical line
\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]