# "Beamer-style" title page with logo, title, etc

Tags: titles

I've put together a thesis title page but I want to turn it into a template à la Beamer. That is: I want to define variables for the title, author, supervisor, university logo and name and jury members--this last one optional!

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=1.8cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vfill
{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png}\par
\fontsize{29}{25}\selectfont
\textbf{The Poison Ivy University}
\par
    {
        \fontsize{15}{13}\selectfont Doctoral Programme on Antidisestablishmentarianist Phisphology at the Institute of Useless Research and the Department of Occult Sciences
    \par}
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
}

{\fontsize{22}{37}\selectfont%
\textbf{Rather obnoxious, unnecessarily long and incomprehensible title on a very obscure and unimportant topic}}
\vfill
{
    \fontsize{19}{19}\selectfont%
    \textsc{thesis}\par
}

{
    \fontsize{14}{19}\selectfont
    To obtain the futile degree of
\par
}
{
    \fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont
    \textsc{doctor of phisphology}
}
\vfill
{\fontsize{14}{19}\selectfont Submitted by:\par}

{
    \fontsize{18}{16}\selectfont%
    Bashed Grad Student\par
}
\vfill

{
    \fontsize{16}{16}\selectfont% 
    Advisor: 

    Herr Prof. Dr. Hab. Merkwürdige Liebe
\par} 

{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont Department of Explosive Relaxation, PIU\par}
\vfill

{
    \fontsize{14}{25}\selectfont%
    Members of the Jury:\par
}

    {
    \fontsize{18}{25}\selectfont
    Dr. Prost. Vogon Jeltz\par
        {
        \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont Department of Transplutonian Literary Theory, PIU
        \par
        }
    }

    {
    \fontsize{18}{25}\selectfont
    Dr. Hab. Gent. Tristram Shandy\par
    }
    {
    \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont Department of Lifes and Opinions, PIU
    \par
    }

\vfill
{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont {Arkham, Massachusetts, Brumaire \textsc{anno v}}}
\end{center}
\vfill
\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

There are many questions that ask on formatting of a title page (e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234265/unam-thesis-title-page-portada-tesis-unam) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207478/thesis-title-page-template-simple-style-with-only-a-vertical-line)) but I think I've got that sorted out. What I want are variables for the contents of the title page; of course the code above requires a beginning and ending of a document, but in real-life I'd like just to input the "variables" on the preamble and use a \maketitle command or something simimlar to produce the output; that is, I want to be able to type in the preamble something like \institution, \advisor, \jurymember (this one is optional), \advisor, etc.

Any ideas?

PS. I include the logo.png file and a screencap of the output just for the sake of completeness.

[image: logo]
[image: output]

Comment: Why? This is a one-off. Unless you plan to complete multiple higher degrees at the same institution, you'll only ever typeset one of these pages. (And they'll probably change the format in between in the time it takes to complete a second anyway.) So there is nothing to be gained by defining variables - it will just increase the complexity.